# androidL how to reset a timer

Tags: android, time, timer, android-5.0-lollipop

I am learning to use a timer, and follow the example in http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/.

I would like to implement in a way that the timer will start off when the user is pressing the button and stop when the user's hand is off, so I have coded as follows:

### Codes:

```
button_right.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
        {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);



        if((event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL))
        {
            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
        }
        return false;
    }
});  



// setting timer
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        tv_timing.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

### Questions:

Everything works fine, and the timer will start when the user presses the button, keep running when holding and stop when hand is off. Yet I discover that when the user presses the button again, the timer start off from where it stops last time instead of resetting to 0 before counting time.

If using this code, how could it be modified such that the timer is reset to 0 so as to count all over again when the button is being pressed again? Thanks!!

Comment: can't you use a boolean value that only false when ACTION_UP? If when ACTION_DOWN it's false, then turn it to true and reset, else count++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

digging further details in the code and researching further through the web, i found an answer and modify the code as follows and it works.

All in all, thanks Monica for introducing the chronometer, it seems nice! and thanks Zyoo for sparkling me to make a removeCallbacks under the ACTION_DOWN

```
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
            {
                if(startTime == 0L)
                {
                    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                }

            if((event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL))
            {
                // timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds; //remove this! 
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                startTime = 0L;
            }
            return false;


private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        //updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;  //remove this!! else starting from where it stops last time!

        int secs = (int) (timeInMilliseconds / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (timeInMilliseconds % 1000);
        tv_timing.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [chronometer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin/Jetty_WTP_Install) in android... you can use its function to stop, start, restart, set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

Only use Chronometer if your timer does not need milliseconds.

Another option for resetting the timer is to add this 1 line: `timeSwapBuff = 0L;`. It is simpler than removing 2 separate ones.

Make this change in the `onClick` event for the Start Button. This resets the time buffer to 0 which then gets added back to the `startTime` (also 0) and forces the timer to start over completely.

Try:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}
```